# PHP Group array alphabetically regarding language-specific conventions

Tags: php, arrays, localization, group-by, sorting

I'm looking for a smart solution that sorts strings with extended characters. It's always a question of the used language. Let's take German for example: A and Ä can sometimes be sorted as if they were the same letter ([**DIN 5007/1**](http://www.nia.din.de/cmd?artid=80825245&bcrumblevel=1&contextid=nia&subcommitteeid=96878767&level=tpl-art-detailansicht&committeeid=54738935&languageid=en)), and sometimes Ä can be sorted as it was in fact "AE" ([**DIN 5007/2**](http://www.nia.din.de/cmd?artid=2751570&bcrumblevel=1&contextid=nia&subcommitteeid=96878767&level=tpl-art-detailansicht&committeeid=54738935&languageid=en)). In Swedish, in contrast, Ä comes at the end of the alphabet.

A list of such conventions for various languages can be found at [Alphabetical order: Language-specific conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order#Language-specific_conventions).

Whats the fastest method, to **group a array like DIN 5007/1**?

```
$array = array
(
    0 => 'Agile',
    1 => 'Ágile',
    2 => 'Àgile',
    3 => 'Âgile',
    4 => 'Ägile',
    5 => 'Ãgile',
    6 => 'Test',
);

// Grouped Result:

Array
(
    'A' => array
    (
        [0] => Agile
        [1] => Àgile
        [2] => Ágile
        [3] => Âgile
        [4] => Ãgile
        [5] => Ägile
    ),
    'T' => array
    (
        [0] => Test
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a fast method, to group an array like DIN 5007/1. At least I don't see one.

There are two aspects that need to be taken into account for a solution: Sorting algorithm which respects sorting according to DIN 5007/1. Grouping the results which respects the similarity caused by special characters.

## Sorting

You can set `SORT_LOCAL_STRING` when using [`array_multisort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) parameter. Remember to choose appropriate locale information (e.g. `de_DE`) by setting [`setlocal()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) before.

```php
// randomly sorted terms
$array = array(
    'Agile',
    'Ágile',
    'Test',
    'Âgile',
    'Ägile',
    'Ãgile',
    'Àgile',
);

setlocale(LC_ALL, '');
array_multisort($array, SORT_ASC, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
print_r($array);
```

But this does not lead to your wanted result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Agile
    [1] => Test
    [2] => Àgile
    [3] => Ágile
    [4] => Âgile
    [5] => Ãgile
    [6] => Ägile
)
```

You will have to take a deep dive into available locales, maybe manually adding all relevant locales works.

> Category/locale names can be found in » [RFC 1766](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1766) and » [ISO 639](http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/IG/ert/iso639.htm). [(source)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

## Grouping

There is a [well-working algorithm for grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/982369/1828051) by using pre-defined groups. This means you will either have to manually define mapping tables (e.g. `Ä = A` and `Ö = O` ...).

Or you could implement a similarity check, e.g. [`similar_text()`](http://www.php.net/similar_text) or [`levenshtein()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php).

## SQL as alternative?

In how far this problem could be implemented more effectively and efficiently in SQL requires further contemplation.

Comment: Up-front: Slap me if this can be done by a narrow three-liner!