# SQL Group By Date But Maintain Records

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I assume the `php/cakephp/sql` parliance.
I have a `History` table which contains the column created of type `DATETIME.`
I would show all the records of the History but arranged by day.

```
------------------------------------------
id   created                what
------------------------------------------
1    2014-01-01 08:00:00   Someone ran
2    2014-01-01 09:00:00   Someone cried
2    2014-01-02 10:00:00   Someone spoke
2    2014-01-02 18:00:00   Someone worked
```

And the result I am looking for

```
array(
'2014-01-01' => array(
                      0=>array('time'=>'8:00','what'=>'Someone ran'
                      1=>array('time'=>'9:00','what'=>'Someone cried'
                     ),
'2014-01-02' => array(
                      0=>array('time'=>'10:00','what'=>'Someone spoke',
                      1=>array('time'=>'18:00','what'=>'Someone worked',
                     )
)
```

I am totaly stucked. Which SQL statement should I investigate? GROUP is not good...

Comment: This can't be done in a single sql statement.  You can run two different sql statement to fetch the groups seperately.  Otherwise, you have to do this in php.

Comment: Can you elaborate an answer?

Comment: I don't know php I am afraid.  If this was c# you could run a sql query to get all records, then use linq to group on the date.  Hopefully someone in the php tag knows how to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouping arrays in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982344/grouping-arrays-in-php)

Comment: have you looked into order by? Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you are just sorting the data by the created date in chronological order.

Comment: The problem is that after sorting I have to "group" although this word is misleading, beacuse actually I want to make groups not "to group".

Comment: @Blanchard It is not a duplicate but a variation on the theme. If this is annoying let me know and I'll cancel the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the other reviewers agree, I would give my answer in cakephp   adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982344/grouping-arrays-in-php)

```
 $histories = $this->History->find('all',
                    array(
                        'group'=>array('History.created')
            ));


 foreach ($histories as $item) {
                $key = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($item['History']['created']));
                if (!isset($groups[$key])) {
                    $groups[$key] = array(
                        'items' => array($item),
                        'count' => 1,
                    );
                } else {
                    $groups[$key]['items'][] = $item;
                    $groups[$key]['count'] += 1;
                }
            }
```