# Grouping in array

Tags: php

I have following array..I am trying to group this.

```
  Array
   (
     [0] => Array
    (
        [Title] => HoMedics MAN-300
        [ean] => 31262006288
        [upc] => 31262006288
        [ProductImageName] => 
        [CdnUri] => 
        [ASIN] => B000050FEU
        [ListPrice] => 129.99
        [Status] => 2
        [ActualPrice] => 129.99
        [ProductID] => 5286728
    )

 )
```

I want to group this into

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [VitalInfo]=>array(
            [Title] => HoMedics MAN-300 
            [ean] => 31262006288
            [upc] => 31262006288
            [ProductImageName] => 
            [CdnUri] => 
            [ASIN] => B000050FEU
       )
       [Price]=>array(
             [ListPrice] => 129.99
            [Status] => 2
            [ActualPrice] => 129.99
            [ProductID] => 5286728
        )
   )
```

I tried but it doesn't happen as I want ...any help would be great...Thanx in advance..

Comment: What have to tried so far? Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,
**CODE** :

```
foreach($old_array as $key_old => $val_old)
 {
    foreach($val_old as $key => $val)
    {
        if(in_array($key, $VitalInfo_array))
        {
            $new_array[$key_old]['VitalInfo'][$key] = $val;
        }
        else
        {
            $new_array[$key_old]['Price'][$key] = $val;
        }
    }
 }
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [VitalInfo] => Array
                (
                    [Title] => HoMedics MAN-300
                    [ean] => 31262006288
                    [upc] => 31262006288
                    [ProductImageName] => 
                    [CdnUri] => 
                    [ASIN] => B000050FEU
                )

            [Price] => Array
                (
                    [ListPrice] => 129.99
                    [Status] => 2
                    [ActualPrice] => 129.99
                    [ProductID] => 5286728
                )

        )

)
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/KgD3Z)**

i hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Simply loop through your array and customize a new array accordingly.

Assuming $array is the original array, and $result is the customized array, try this:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $arr) {

    $result[$k]['VitalInfo'] = array(
        'Title'            =>  $arr['Title'],
        'ean'              =>  $arr['ean'],
        'upc'              =>  $arr['upc'],
        'ProductImageName' =>  $arr['ProductImageName'],
        'CdnUri'           =>  $arr['CdnUri'],
        'ASIN'             =>  $arr['ASIN']
    );

    $result[$k]['Price'] = array(
        'ListPrice'   =>  $arr['ListPrice'],
        'Status'      =>  $arr['Status'],
        'ActualPrice' =>  $arr['ActualPrice'],
        'ProductID'   =>  $arr['ProductID']        
    );

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are grouping this in php, have a look at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982344/grouping-arrays-in-php).

Or just copy this:

```
$input = [0 => [
    'Title' => 'HoMedics MAN-300',
    'ean' => 31262006288,
    'upc' => 31262006288,
    'ProductImageName' => '',
    'CdnUri' => '',
    'ASIN' => 'B000050FEU',
    'ListPrice' => 129.99,
    'Status' => 2,
    'ActualPrice' => 129.99,
    'ProductID' => 5286728
]];
foreach ($input as $in){
    $out['VitalInfo'] = [];
    $out['Price'] = [];
    foreach ($in as $key => $i){
        if (in_array($key, ['Title', 'ean', 'upc', 'ProductImageName', 'CdnUri', 'Asin'])){
            $out['VitalInfo'][] = [$key => $i];
        } else {
            $out['Price'][] = [$key => $i];
        }
    }
    $output[]=$out;
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Input : $info // Your Original Array
Ouput : $finalArr // Your Required Array

```
 $vitalInfo = array ('Title','ean','upc','ProductImageName','CdnUri','ASIN');
 $price = array ('ListPrice','Status','ActualPrice','ProductId');    
 $finalArr = array();

 foreach ($info as $arr) {
   $result = array();
   foreach($arr as $k => $v){
       if(in_array($k,$vitalInfo))
            $result['VitalInfo'][$k] = $v;
       else if(in_array($k,$price))
            $result['Price'][$k] = $v;
   }
   $finalArr[] = $result;
}
```